# Java Generics and Map declaration

Tags: java, generics, collections

I am having a hard time declaring a Map using Generics. I'd like to declare a Map with the following properties:

- The key is a Class object of any Type T derived from a particular Interface (IFoo)
- The value of the Map is another Map whose key is an String and whose value is of the Type T

I thought I can do it like this:

```
      public static Map<Class<T extends IFoo>, Map<String, T>> valueCache = 
new HashMap<Class<T extends IFoo>, Map<String, T>>();
```

I get a syntax error on "extends"

If I replace the T Types with wildcards (?) like this it seems to be syntactically correct:

```
    public static Map<Class<? extends Typ>, Map<Integer, ?>> valueCache= 
new HashMap<Class<? extends Typ>, Map<Integer, ?>>();
```

But I don't think this is what I want since I want to be exactly the type of the Class object to be the value in the second map.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hmm. This is a static field. There is only every one copy of it. Shouldn't that type be known already? Why do you need a placeholder?  How can it have a generic type when there can be no instances?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to have such a declaration outside of a generic class. But if the field was not public, you could at least use generic methods to access it and make sure the types match. public static variables are the devil.

Comment: You can't _really_ do this:  you can't make the `Class` type correspond the the values.

Comment: Your `T` must be declared somewhere. Where?

Comment: @JBNizet: you are right about the public, this is a lapse in my example... Thank for the hint with the static methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic type parameter can only be declared on a class or method declaration.

If you don't care about the reference type of the `IFoo` that you get back you can do

```
static Map<Class<? extends IFoo>, Map<String, IFoo>> fooMap;
```

If you want to use the `IFoo` returned as its subclass type then you need to do some casting.

```
// abbreviated example
class FooMap {
    private static Map<Class<? extends IFoo>, Map<String, IFoo>> map = ...;

    static void put(String key, IFoo foo) {
        map.get(foo.getClass()).put(key, foo);
    }

    static <F extends IFoo> F get(Class<F> cls, String key) {
        return cls.cast(map.get(cls).get(key));
    }
}

FooMap.put("foo", new Foo());
Foo foo = FooMap.get(Foo.class, "foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the extends into your class's generic definition:

```
public class ClassWithGeneric<T extends IFoo> {
    Map<Class<T>, Map<String, T>> valueCache = new HashMap<Class<T>, Map<String, T>>();
}
```

Comment: But it's a `static` field.

Comment: So far as I know, you can't use generic parameters in static fields. Can you elaborate on why you need this to be a static field?

Answer (score 1):

It's not technically possible to do what you want, but you can simulate it using accessor methods with internal casting. For example:

```
private static Map<Class<?>, Map<String, ?>> valueCache = new HashMap<>();

public <T extends IFoo> Map<String, T> getMap(Class<T> key) {
    return (Map<String, T>)value cache.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public static Map<IFoo, Map<String, IFoo>> valueCache = new HashMap<IFoo, Map<String, IFoo>>();
```

By this way, you make use of the map for IFoo Type Classes.

Answer (score -1):

since you Declaring a Map you should Specify all types it helps a lot and should be always Correct so it should be like T should be a type and not Generic since you declare it so java wants to know the type in the newer Versions of java you dont need to declare the second <> generics so i dont know the second type of your inner map so i used Object

```
public static Map<IFoo,Map<String,Object>valueChache=new Hashmap<>();
```

Both should be Correct

```
public static Map<IFoo,Map<String,Object>valueChache=new Hashmap<IFoo,Map<String,Object>();
```